# asp.net mvc Html.checkboxfor not reflecting values from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 and in my view file I have put a Checkbox using below code. But Model binding is not working. Even if property is set as false the checbox is coming as checked.

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.IsDirectHire)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsDirectHire)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsDirectHire)
    </div>
```

Please help me find a solution

Comment: Put breakpoint before rendering your view, then cjheck the value. If it'OK go through step b step into the view and check again the value.

Comment: Pls can you show your controller?